# Make user install Java from a Mac OS X app

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, java

**OK, here's my situation :**

- I've got an app (I'm about to distribute from within the App Store)
- The app depends on an "included" `.jar` file
- So, for the app to run smoothly, the java runtime must be present on the user OS X installation
- As of recently, *Mountain Lion* strips any previous `Java Runtime` installation
- I know that Java can be installed, when it's needed

**However :**

- my app just got rejected, seemingly because it "did nothing"
- I suspect the issue is that the testing was done on a Mountain Lion - running Mac, withOUT a Java runtime.

**Questions :**

- How do we make sure the Java Runtime is installed
- Why doesn't a call to `/usr/bin/java` trigger the automatic installation of the JRE?
- How do we make the user install the runtime, before we make any use of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple does not allow apps that rely on Java being installed. See for example 
https://blogs.oracle.com/henrik/entry/oracle_jdk_and_javafx_sdk#comment-1335812118020:

> Hi guest - Apple does not disallow Java in the App Store. However,
>   they do not allow an App Store app to rely on any preinstalled
>   functionality except what is present in the OS. If you want to ship
>   your Java app through the Mac App Store, you will have to create a
>   package consisting of your app and a JRE and upload it to Apple as a
>   single unit. We explicitly allow redistribution of the Oracle JDK and
>   JRE in such scenarios; see the license that you accept when you
>   download the JDK for details.

Perhaps this link helps: [Packaging a Java App for Distribution on a Mac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html)

Comment: This seems like a viable solution. Let me see if I can get it working this way, coz it seems the only way I could solve my issue (I'm trying to use YUI-Compressor (http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) and Java seems the only way...). Thanks for the advice! ;-)